# Importing sklearn error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pycharm

So I have been trying to install numpy, scipy and sklearn for a course I am taking. After many issues and numerous attempts, I installed pycharm and used their built in package manager to get numpy and scipy. I also installed sklearn but when I import it in my code i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 1, line 3
  File "C:\Users\Berges\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Berges\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\Berges\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\Berges\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\Berges\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 406, in <module>
    if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

(I am using python 3.5.2 and when u run python3 on bash I can import sklearn just fine but it seems to be using python 3.4.3 for that)

UPDATE:

I installed Anaconda and attempted to run the following code from Wing IDE and Atom:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-3.-2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,2]])
Y = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X,Y)
print(clf.predict([[-0.8,-1]]))
```

I then get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Berges\Downloads\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    clf.fit(X,Y)
  File "C:\Users\Berges\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 173, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\Berges\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 510, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "C:\Users\Berges\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 373, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get something up and running for a course and you want to make it work on Windows. Then I suggest you to install anaconda package manager. It works like a breeze on Windows and is very easy to install and contains all the necessary packages (you don't have to worry about version mismatch and everything).

After you install anaconda manager, change the pycharm interpreter location to anaconda installed python interpreter.

Link: https://www.continuum.io/downloads 
List of available packages: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs

Comment: I see that you are using an example from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html.

Comment: I see that you are using an example from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html.

You made a mistake in the array "X". 
instead of 
`X = np.array([[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-3.-2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,2]])`
it should be 
`X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])`

**Instead of comma you placed a dot. So it comes -5, instead of [-3, -2]**

Answer (score 0):

You missed a small detail that causes this error.

In the X array you type `[-3. -2]` instead of `[-3, -2]`.

**So you missed a comma.**

The following works fine:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)

print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```

**Results:**

```
[1]
```